# Taipy Scenarios not found after a rerun

Tags: database, backend, pipeline, taipy

I created a Taipy application to create scenarios with predictions and metrics, but when I rerun my code after stopping it, I lose all my scenarios and data. Where does it come from? How can I keep my scenarios and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Taipy runs in development mode, which deletes data and scenarios upon each execution.

To retain scenarios, you can use either the 'experiment' or 'production' modes (see the [documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/core/versioning/)).

**To run in 'experiment' mode and create/run version V1:**

`python main.py --experiment V1`

This ensures that your scenarios and data remain intact.

**To run your application with VS Code:**

1. Set up a *launch.json* file (you can create it under the debug tab in VS Code).
2. Add the following to the file (*.vscode/launch.json*):

`"args":["--experiment", "V1"],`